# How can we send a notification on the basis of system exception created in mule application?

Tags: mule, mule-component

I have a requirement where I need to send a mail when system exception occurs in my mule application.

I have created a class which extends `DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy` and also a second class which extends `MuleContextAware`.

I need to find a way to either call a flow which will send an email notification or send a CloudHub alert.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you could do is add a exception strategy component on the flow, add a set-payload or template that should contains the message you want when there is an exception and add a mail component or add a flow that contains the mail component and this one should be called.
[image]

Comment: Hi Alex,   Actually catch exception strategy can not be applied on system exceptions.